# How to prove $\sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{1}{x+yz} \le \frac{9}{2(xy+yz+zx)}$ for all $x,y,z >0:x+y+z=3.$?

Tags: inequality

When I entered a test at my school, I stuck this problem (it is also posted [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=3791430684514275&set=pcb.3791431977847479))

> Let $x,y,z$ be positive real numbers such that $x+y+z=3$, prove that
> $$\frac{1}{x+yz}+\frac{1}{y+zx}+\frac{1}{z+xy} \le
>  \frac{9}{2(xy+yz+zx)}.$$

I have tried AM GM
$$\frac{1}{x+yz}\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{xyz}}.$$
But it leads to a wrong inequality
$$(xy+yz+zx)^2 \le 9xyz=3xyz(x+y+z).$$
Also, I tried SOS or Vonicu Schur without any success. It seems impossible to prove
$$LHS \le \frac{3}{2} \le RHS$$
Could anyone help me with this problem? Thanks alot.

Comment: While it is true that $RHS \geq 3/2$, it need not be true that $LHS \leq 3/2$. EG Take $ x, y \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @CalvinLin sorry for my typo. Btw, I find $3/2 \le LHS\le RHS$

Comment: One can use the pqr method.

Comment: @RiverLi yes, it's very trivial if we use it. But the problem is just a secondary one, so that I just wondered there's a nice proof.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary proof that does not require the $pqr$ method (however using it will tremendously speed up the proof). Notice that:
$$\frac{1}{x+yz}=\frac{3}{3x+3yz}=\frac{3}{x^2+xy+xz+3yz}.$$
Using this representation and summing over the cyclic terms, we have the following result after some tedious simplification:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+yz}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{3}{x^2+xy+xz+3yz}=\frac{12(x+y+z)^2(xy+yz+zx)}{\prod_{cyc}(x^2+xy+xz+3yz)}=\frac{4(xy+yz+yx)}{\prod_{cyc}(x+yz)}.$$
Therefore, the original inequality simplifies to:
$$ 9(x+yz)(y+zx)(z+xy) - 8(xy+yz+xz)^2\geq 0.$$
By expanding the polynomial, one can show that:
$$9(x+yz)(y+zx)(z+xy) - 8(xy+yz+xz)^2 - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2z^2=9xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4),$$
and it thus suffices to show that $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4\geq 0$. This can be proved by a standard Lagrange Multiplier. The first order condition is:
$$
2x+yz-\lambda = 0\\
2y+xz-\lambda = 0\\
2z+xy-\lambda = 0\\
x+y+z=3
$$
And the solutions are $(x,y,z,\lambda)=(1,1,1,3)$ and $(-1,2,2,2)$ (up to a permutation). Clearly, there is only one solution that satisfies the requirement that $x,y,z>0$. By checking the Hessian matrix, we can confirm that $(x^*,y^*,z^*)=(1,1,1)$ is the global minimum under the constraints on $x,y,z$. Therefore: $x^2+y^2+z^2+xyz-4\geq 1^2+1^2+1^2+1-4=0$ as desired. This completes the proof.

Comment: Very nice idea, thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Not a very elegant solution, but works (Schurhead + Triangle notation). Homogenize before expansion:
$$0\leq\frac{9}{2 (x y+x z+y z)}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3} x (x+y+z)+y z}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3} y (x+y+z)+x
   z}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{3} z (x+y+z)+x y}$$
Then we're left to prove:
$$x^4 y^2+14 x^4 y z+x^4 z^2+2 x^3 y^3-10 x^3 y^2 z-10 x^3 y z^2+2 x^3 z^3+x^2 y^4-$$$$-10
   x^2 y^3 z+6 x^2 y^2 z^2-10 x^2 y z^3+x^2 z^4+14 x y^4 z-10 x y^3 z^2-10 x y^2
   z^3+$$$$+14 x y z^4+y^4 z^2+2 y^3 z^3+y^2 z^4\geq0$$

Use the [triangle](https://stuff.mit.edu/%7Eevanchen/handouts/SOS_Dumbass/SOS_Dumbass.pdf) notation:
[image]

Then we notice the Schur pattern around the central 6, subtract
$$2xyz(x(x-y)(x-z)+y(y-x)(y-z)+z(z-x)(z-y))$$
Then we're left with:
[image]

Which can be Cleared by Muirhead since it's $ S[4, 2, 0] +  S[3, 3, 0] + 6 S[4, 1, 1] \geq 8 S[3, 2, 1]$